# Installed 20.04 , lost network interfaces

Tags: networking, 20.04

Dell T420 sever; BCM5720 interfaces are gone after upgrade from 19.10
ifconfig  lists only "lo" and "tun0"

/etc/netword/interfaces  show "auto lo em1" and "iface em1 inet static" ... (with settings)

lspci proves that the ethernet adapters are there, how can I make them be used by Ubuntu 20.04 (server)